# Type-mismatch/run-time error in case of CDate/IsDate

Tags: vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I would like to count the number of the cells which contain dates which are older then 1 year.

But I see cells with incorrect date format or text, so in case of IsDate=false I would like to delete the contents of the cells. After I check with the next If cycle is it older than 1 year or not.

But I get **type-mismatch** error in case of cell which cointains "201.07.01" (instead of 2021.07.01). But the IsDate is True in this case too.

```
If IsDate(Cells(1, 1)) = True Then
Else
Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
End If

If Cells(1, 1) + 365 < Date Then
MsgBox ("older")
Else
MsgBox ("not older")
End If
```

I tried to replace "." to "-" and convert the content of the cell to date with CDate with the following code but in this cade I get **Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.**

```
Cells(1, 1) = Replace(Cells(1, 1), ".", "-")

If IsDate(Cells(1, 1)) = True Then
Cells(1, 1) = CDate(Cells(1, 1))
Else
Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
End If

If Cells(1, 1) + 365 < Date Then
MsgBox ("older")
Else
MsgBox ("not older")
End If
```

What can be the issue and how could I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume cell A1 has the string "201.07.01". Excel recognises this as a string.

**Short Story:**

- You got your first error because `Cells(1, 1) + 365` attempts to add a string to a number.
- You got your second error because `Cells(1, 1) = CDate(Cells(1, 1))` tries to enter a date that excel doesn't recognise.

**Long Story:**

The issue is the way dates are represented in Excel vs VBA. Try:

```
Sub excel_vs_vba_dates()
  Debug.Print "Day 1 in Excel: ", WorksheetFunction.Text(1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  Debug.Print "Day 1 in VBA: ", Format(1, "yyyy-mm-dd")

  'Excel doesn't accept negative numbers as dates
  On Error Resume Next
  Debug.Print "Day -100 in Excel: ", WorksheetFunction.Text(-100, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  Debug.Print Err.Description
  On Error GoTo 0
  
  'Negative numbers are valid dates in vba
  Debug.Print "Day -100 in VBA: ", Format(-100, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  
  Debug.Print "201-07-01 in VBA: ", Format(CDate("201-07-01"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
  
  Dim lng As Long: lng = DateSerial(Year(CDate("201-07-01")), _
                                    Month(CDate("201-07-01")), _
                                    Day(CDate("201-07-01")))
  Debug.Print "201-07-01 as a number in VBA: ", lng
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Day 1 in Excel:             1900-01-01
Day 1 in VBA:               1899-12-31
Unable to get the Text property of the WorksheetFunction class
Day -100 in VBA:            1899-09-21
201-07-01 in VBA:           0201-07-01
201-07-01 as a number in VBA:             -620364
```

This is why `Cells(1, 1) = CDate(Cells(1, 1))` will raise an error if the value in that cell is "201.07.01" as you are trying to copy into Excel a date that it doesn't recognise. *Please note using "." or "-" depends of your system's locale settings.*

On the other hand, if you use `CDate(Cells(1, 1))` in your code, then VBA is happy to use it as the date "1st of July 201".

The following function works for me:

```
Function checkDate(rng As Range) As String
  Set rng = rng.Cells(1, 1)
  
  If IsDate(rng.Value) Then
    If CDate(rng.Value) < DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date) Then
      checkDate = "older"
    Else
      checkDate = "not older"
    End If
  Else
    rng.ClearContents
    checkDate = "invalid date"
  End If
End Function

Sub testDate()
  MsgBox checkDate(Cells(1, 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think my code follows the same logic. If IsDate fails, delete the contents of the cell, so in the next cycle could not cause issues. But IsDate is true in case of "201.07.01", this is my problem.

But I have just tried to change the sequence as you wrote, the issues is the same, if I use "Cells(1, 1) + 365 < Date". But if I use "rng.Value < DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date)", I do not get error message but the result is that 201.07.01 is not older than 1 year.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Try `CDate(Cells(1, 1)) + 365 < Date` or `CDate(rng.Value) < DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date)`. I changed my code also.

Comment: Thank you very much you for your help and detailed explanation! :) Now I understand why give me IsDate true value but CDate type-mismatch error. And thanks for your recommendation about "." and "-". I forget to write that I have already tried it also because once I spent hours with this issue (I used "." and the code worked well on my notebook but gave type-mismatch error on other notebook...).

Answer (score 0):

Try this case

```
If IsDate(Cells(1, 1)) = True Then
   on error resume next
   Cells(1, 1) = CDate(Cells(1, 1))
   If err.Number>0 then
     Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
     MsgBox ("Error date")
   ElseIf (Cells(1, 1) + 365) < Date Then
     Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
     MsgBox ("older")
   Else
     MsgBox ("not older")
   End If
   on error go to 0
Else
   Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
   MsgBox ("No date")
End If
```

Upd1. We can check `is Cell(1,1) is true date` using  `error-handling`.
Potentially error can issued on check CDate(...). If error occurs - cell not contains valid `date`.

In your case Err.Number=13 and Err.Description="Type mismatch".

After an error is handled by an error handler in procedure, execution resumes in the current procedure at the point designated by the Resume statement. We set `resume next` - continue execution on next command.
Next statement - check value in the Number property of the Err object to determine the cause of the error.

```
   'activate error handling
    on error resume next
    Cells(1, 1) = CDate(Cells(1, 1)) -- there my be error issue
    If err.Number>0 then  -- err.number<>0 - error happened
       do something when error
    else -- no error
       do something when cell is realy date
    endif
    on error go to 0  -- ' Turn off error trapping and clear err.Number
```

Comment: Many thnks, it works! But I do not see the logic. I think my code do someting similar because that should delete cell content if IsDate=false but IsDate=True in case of "201.07.01." but CDate give me error message. What is the difference between the 2 codes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Difference in error handling. I update answer with some comment about error handling

Comment: Thank you very much you for your help and detailed explanation! :) This method is going to help me in other topics too.